# How to automate Grafana dashboard creation for micrometer metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, micrometer, microprofile

I use micrometer specification to generate metrics and I want to automate my Grafana dashboards creation.

There is dashboard generator but for microprofile apps.
https://github.com/jamesfalkner/microprofile-grafana

Any one can help please?

Answer (score 1):

I have created this online tool to automate this Grafana dashboard creation

You can use it online: http://eljah.tatar/micrometer2grafana/

You can just copy the principle in your own implementation from my code of this tool https://github.com/Eljah/micrometer2grafana

It uses very basic templating.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried your tool but it doesn't work. It generates a not valid json.

Comment: @Laka what kind of invalidity you got? May be the JSON is specific for some Grafana version is needed? Could you provide the micrometer data sample, that causes the problem?

Comment: @Laka i see the problem, thank you for the reporting!